# Avoid angle brackets in default template

Tags: c++, templates, coding-style, class-template

If I have a template class with a default template type, I have to write the template angle brackets. **Is it somehow possible to avoid this?**

Example:

```
template <typename T=int>
class tt {
public:
  T get() { return 5; }
};

...

tt<> t;  // how to avoid <>
std::cout << t.get() << std::endl;
```

Until now i've did this by a separate namespace and redeclaring the class:

```
namespace detail_ {
template <typename T=int>
class tt {
public:
  T get() { return 5; }
};
}

class tt : public detail_::tt {}

...

tt t;
std::cout << t.get() << std::endl;
```

The problem is, if I want to use the class with an other type I have to go over namespace detail_. **Is there another solution**, which I didn't see yet.

Comment: what is the problem with `<>`? Having both `tt` and `tt<Foo>` being valid types is impossible afaik.

Comment: @ArneMertz the problem is just the style.

Comment: So what's the problem with that style? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++17, because of [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), things [have changed](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7OuyNQLuzYgGOjAA).

`tt` and `tt<>` are not the same thing: types and class templates were different and continue to be treated differently.

Anyway in simple scenarios like the one in your example, C++17 assumes what you mean and the `<>` aren't needed anymore.

Further details:

- [Template default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15373823/3235496) (specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970942/3235496);
- [Why is <> required when specifying a template class which has defaults for all its template parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42670137/3235496)

Answer (score 8):

*... if I want to use the class ...*

This is a common source of confusion. A class template is not a class, but a template from which classes are generated. The angle brackets is what tells the compiler that you want to generate a class out of the class template with the given template arguments, without the angle brackets what you have is a *template*.

```
template <typename T = int>
struct TemplateClass { /*...*/ };

template <template <typename>  class T>
void f() {
   T<int> t; // ...
}
template <typename T>
void g() {
   T t; // ...
}

f<TemplateClass>();     // Accepts a template with a single type argument
g<TemplateClass<> >();  // Accepts a type, that can be generated out of the template
```

The language does not allow the coexistence of a template and a type with the same name in the same namespace, so the answer is that it cannot be done. You can create a type alias but you will have to give it a different name.

Comment: David, thank you for your good answer, it served well for the past few years. But since C++17 I think the answer by @manlio does suite better. Therefor I switched the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use typedef...

```
typedef tt<> tt_;
```

And then simply use `tt_`.

Comment: Hm. that typedef saves you one character to type for every time you would use `tt<>`. The typedef itself, including spaces and the newline at its end, take 18 characters to type. Plus the loss of readability, since it's clear that `tt<>` is related to the template, but `tt_` might be something different. You still cannot use the same name for the template and its default instantiation. So is it worth it? ;)

Comment: How's about `typedef detail_::tt<> tt'`?