# why <> is empty in adjacency_list<>

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

Can I ask what the `<>` is for in `adjacency_list<>` ? I am new to stl. I know I can define a container like this: `vector<int> vec`, but why here it is empty in `<>`? Thank you.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
    using namespace boost;
    adjacency_list<> g;
    // adds four vertices to the graph
    adjacency_list<>::vertex_descriptor v1 = add_vertex(g);
    adjacency_list<>::vertex_descriptor v2 = add_vertex(g);
    adjacency_list<>::vertex_descriptor v3 = add_vertex(g);
    adjacency_list<>::vertex_descriptor v4 = add_vertex(g);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template default arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373823/template-default-arguments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because [`adjacency_list` is a templated type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html). You must specify `<>` when using C++ templates.

The full definition for the type is:

```
template <class OutEdgeListS = vecS,
          class VertexListS = vecS,
          class DirectedS = directedS,
          class VertexProperty = no_property,
          class EdgeProperty = no_property,
          class GraphProperty = no_property,
          class EdgeListS = listS>
class adjacency_list
{
    ...
}
```

Notice that each template parameter has a default: `vecS`, `vecS`, `directedS`, `no_property`, `no_property`, `no_property`, `listS`, respectively.

The empty `<>` means you want the default classes for the template parameters. By not specifying the specific values for the template parameters, you get the defaults.

The reason `<>` is needed, and can't be left out (which would be nice, yes) is because of the way the C++ language has been defined. [You can avoid it by using a `typedef`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014736/avoid-angle-brackets-in-default-template), but ultimately the angle brackets are required for using template types.