# C++: Default template argument only deduced when using "<>"

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I created this `struct` for some easy templated Math definitions:

```
template<class T = float> struct Math{
    static constexpr T PI = T(3.14159265359);
    static constexpr T E = T(2.718281828459);
    static constexpr T INF = std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity();
};
```

I would like to use it like this:

```
float pi = Math::PI;
```

Even if the default argument `T` is `float` Ill get the error:

```
'template<class T> struct Math' used without template parameters
```

If I use `Math<>::PI` it works. Is this a compiler bug or are the `<>` brackets mandatory?

Comment: why don't you just use `double` for all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the `<>` brackets are mandatory (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812389/avoiding-brackets-for-class-template-having-default-parameter)).

But here are some other options:

use a typedef

```
typedef Math<> MyDefaultMath
// or
typedef Math<float> MyFloatMath
```

or just drop the template

```
struct Math
{
    static constexpr float PI = 3.14159265359f;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a compiler bug or are the <> brackets mandatory?

No, it's not a bug they are mandatory.

However, you may want to give this a little more thought. What if someone uses `Math<int>`? For example the documentation of [`std::numeric_limits::infinity`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity) states the following:

> Only meaningful if std::numeric_limits::has_infinity == true

Comment: Thanks, this is ofcourse true. I would have used the template mainly for `float` and `double`.

Answer (score 1):

The empty brackets are mandatory and required by the standard. From [temp.arg], emphasis mine:

> When template argument packs or default template-arguments are used, a template-argument list can be
>   empty. In that case the empty `<>` brackets **shall still be used** as the template-argument-list. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T = char> class String;
> String<>* p; // OK: String<char>
> String* q; // syntax error
>
> template<class ... Elements> class Tuple;
> Tuple<>* t; // OK: Elements is empty
> Tuple* u; // syntax error
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*